# Rails show raised exception in form view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my application a user can belong to a team. A captain can invite any one user to any one team as long as that user doesn't already belong to a team. I have an invite model that will check if that user belongs to a team before sending the invite.

```
class Invite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user

  before_create :check_membership

  def check_membership
    @memberships = self.user.teams.map { |t| t.id }

    if @memberships.include?(self.team.id) 
      raise 'That user is already on a team'
    end
  end
end
```

If the user does belong to a team and is invited by a captain, I want there to be an error message that alerts the captain they are already on a team.

To do this I created a method to check if the user belongs to a team and, if they do, to raise an exception. I would like to show this exception in the view by putting this in the form.

```
<% if invite.errors.any? %>
  <ul>
    <% test.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
      <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

When I send the invite to a test user, it just shows that error message in the typical rails error page rather than showing the error message above the form in re-render. How do I make this exception message show up in the form after submitting it?

[image]

Comment: The `errors` referenced in the code is https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validations-overview-errors, not RuntimeExceptions. It gets populated by validating your model.

Comment: An exception is the wrong approach here; this is validation, as Steve says. Exceptions are for *exceptional* cases, not things that could trivially happen based on user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to raise an exception, you just want to add a validation to the Invite model.

```
validate :check_membership

def check_membership
  return if persisted?
  if user.teams.include?(team)
    errors.add(:base, 'The user is already on the team')
  end
end
```

The `errors` for invite will then include the above error if it occurs.

You can indeed trap conditions by raising an exception, but that will, by design, halt the program unless you rescue from the exception.  Which you could do, but that's overkill for tihs case.

Comment: By the way, I note the requirement for this only to happen on create, and have edited the answer to reflect that.